# como hacer un ciclo o bucle que sume una cantidad hasta que sea positiva

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Mi duda es como como hacer un ciclo o bucle que sume una cantidad **`hasta que sea positiva`**

**Ejemplo:**

```
-870+360 = -510

-510+360= -150

-150+360 = 210
```

y solo muestre el resultado positivo es decir **210** en el ejemplo

Comment: y cual es el còdigo que has intentado?

Comment: @Jorgesys  intente con while , pero solo repite la misma suma , no se como hacer que guarde el resultado de la primera suma y lo siga sumando por el valor indicado y pare cuando sea mayor que cero

Comment: Agregue una forma mediante un while,  va a realizar la suma mientras que el valor sea negativo, al final obtendrìas el valor 210 @LiantonyPozo

Comment: @LiantonyPozo añadir por favor el código que intentó.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes realizar mediante un `while` y usando el operador += , teniendo como resultado `210`:

```
    int valor = -870;
    while(valor < 0){
      valor+= 360;    
    }

   System.out.println("valor resultante : " +  valor);
```

teniendo como salida:

```
valor resultante : 210
```

Comment: Lo probaste? estas seguro que no entrarà al while ? Dev. Joel ?

Comment: estaba utilizando el while  repitiendo la suma dentro del {} ese era mi error  , no tome el cuenta la modificacion que tienes de valor +=360;

Comment: gracias :) fue de  mucha ayuda

Answer (score 0):

```
x=valor_inicial;
for (i=valor_inicial;i<=0;i+=360){
x=i;
}
```

Comment: Jamás entrará al `for`, ya qué el valor inicial será negativo. no cumple la condición del `for`

Comment: perdón, me equivoque de símbolo. deja lo cambio